# how to set the max length to TextareaAutosize

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, web-frontend

I need my TextareaAutosize max length is 60 , i set the property inputProps equal 60, it doesn't work.

```
    <TextareaAutosize classes={classes.textarea} ref={textAreaRef} aria-label="empty textarea" rowsMin={5} inputProps={{"maxLength":60}} placeholder="60 Character Limit" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **For `maxLength` you put it directly to props**

Because `TextareaAutosize` inherit from `HTMLTextAreaElement`

```
<TextareaAutosize
  classes={classes.textarea}
  ref={textAreaRef}
  aria-label="empty textarea"
  rowsMin={5}
  maxLength={60}
  placeholder="60 Character Limit"
/>;
```

**Live example:**

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]